# Let $R$ be a ring such that for every $x\in R$, we have $x^2=x$

Tags: ring-theory

The first problem is "prove that $y=-y$ for every $y\in R$" And as a hint, my professor noted that try squaring some elements of $R$ to see if they tell anything.
But I don't understand the hint. Could you give a couple of examples for that? 
Also, I am asking the guide line for the proof as well.

Comment: Have you tried squaring some of the elements?  What do you notice?

Comment: That is what I am confused.. What do you mean by element? like 1,2,3?

Answer (score 2):

We have $y=y^2=(-y)^2=\cdots$? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Isn't it $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @Wes Come again? ${}{}{}$

Comment: $1=1^2=(-1)^2=1$.? I am really not sure.

Comment: @Wes The element $y$ is an arbitrary element of the ring. $-y$ is its additive inverse. In any ring $(-1)(-1)=1$.

Comment: I think I don't understand what elements are in the Ring. So, when my prof. said try some element in $R$, I am not sure what element to pick? What is element in $R$?

Comment: @Wes Can you tell me examples of rings?

Comment: Only thing I know is that Ring is a set of numbers that have addition and multiplication. So, example can be like, $a,b,c,d$, $a+b=c$ etc.?

Comment: @Wes A ring has very specific "rules"; so to speak. It is a set $R$ equipped with two operations, $+,\cdot$, and two distinguished elements $1\neq 0$, such that $(R,+,0)$ is an (additive) abelian group and $(R,\cdot,1)$ (some people don't ask for a $1$) is a monoid, and such that distributive laws hold: $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ and $(a+b)c=ac+bc$.